# Removing comments from a datafile. What are the differences?

Tags: unix, sed, grep, command

Let's say that you would like to remove comments from a datafile using one of two methods:

```
cat file.dat | sed -e "s/\#.*//"
cat file.dat | grep -v "#"
```

How do these individual methods work, and what is the difference between them? Would it also be possible for a person to write the clean data to a new file, while avoiding any possible warnings or error messages to end up in that datafile? If so, how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do these individual methods work, and what is the difference
>   between them?

Yes, they work same though `sed` and `grep` are 2 different commands. Your `sed` command simply substitutes all those lines which having `#` with NULL. On other hand `grep` will simply skip or ignore those lines which will skip lines which have `#` in it.

You could get more information on these by man page as follows:

`man grep`:

> ```
>    -v, --invert-match
>           Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

`man sed`:

> ```
>    s/regexp/replacement/
>           Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.   The
> ```
>
> replacement  may
>                 contain  the  special  character  & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1
>   through \9 to
>                 refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

---

---

> Would it also be possible for a person to write the clean data to a
>   new file, while avoiding any possible warnings or error messages to
>   end up in that datafile?

yes, we could re-direct the errors by using `2>/dev/null` in both the commands.

> If so, how would you go about doing this?

You could try like `2>/dev/null 1>output_file`

***Explanation of `sed` command:*** Adding explanation of `sed` command too now. This is only for understanding purposes and no need to use `cat` and then use `sed` you could use `sed -e "s/\#.*//"  Input_file` instead.

```
sed -e "  ##Initiating sed command here with adding the script to the commands to be executed
s/        ##using s for substitution of regexp following it.
\#.*      ##telling sed to match a line if it has # till everything here.
//"       ##If match found for above regexp then substitute it with NULL.
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the sed command deducts this from "s/\#.*//"?

Answer (score 0):

That `grep -v` will lose all the lines that have `#` on them, for example:

```
$ cat file
first
# second
thi # rd
```

so

```
$ grep -v "#" file
first
```

will drop off all lines with `#` on it which is not favorable. Rather you should:

```
$ grep -o "^[^#]*" file
first
thi
```

like that `sed` command does but this way you won't get empty lines. `man grep`:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```